# Simple Calculation using PHP and JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, joomla3.0, virtuemart

I am trying to create a simple calculator on our website. Which doesn't refresh the page when the function is run.

I have two numbers, only one of which is user inputted. I have the .php file and an external .js file. I am very new to JavaScript.

My php code:

```
<?php
$packsize = round($this->product->product_packaging, 2); ?>
<p id="packsize"><?php echo $packsize ?></p>
<form action="" id="floorcalc" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="floorinput" id="floorinput" />
</form>
<button onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>

<p id="calcresult"></p>

<script type="text/javascript" src="public_html/templates/avant/js/floorcalc.js"></script>
```

My JavaScrpit file floorcalc.js :

```
function Calculate() {
 var forminput = document.getElementById("floorinput");
 var rqarea = 0;
 var packdiv = document.getElementById("packsize");
 var packsize = packdiv.textContent;

 if (forminput.value!="") {
    rqarea =  parseInt(forminput.value);
 }

 var result = rqarea / packsize;

 document.getElementById("calcresult").innerHTML = result
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is the user inputted value to be used in a calculation, then shown on the page in the `<p id="calcresults">`.

The button doesn't seem to do anything at all.

My question is: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: `<button type='button' onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>`

Comment: Updated my question, doing so many different things, I didn't finish my question haha, apologies.
PS. still not working with the addition of type="button"

Comment: I did something similar long ago, and the solution I found to avoid the page refresh was to use a JavaScript segment within the PHP. PHP meaning Hypertext Preprocessor (emphasis on the PRE) handles all of the rendering on the server side prior to the page loading. I think you'll need to use JavaScript, or AJAX to handle real-time calculations without page refreshing (if I am understanding your question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine as pure HTML. Things to check would be that the path to the js file is correct and if there are console errors. I would also check the source in the browser to check that php isn't doing something odd to your button.

Comment: Seemed like the source ref was slightly wrong. changed it to /templates/avant/js/floorcalc.js

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Calculate() {
 var forminput = document.getElementById("floorinput");
 var rqarea = 0;
 var packdiv = document.getElementById("packsize");
 var packsize = packdiv.textContent;

 if (forminput.value!="") {
    rqarea =  parseInt(forminput.value);
 }

 var result = rqarea / packsize;

 document.getElementById("calcresult").innerHTML = result
}
```

```html
<p id="packsize">123</p>
<form action="" id="floorcalc" method="POST">
 <input type="text" name="floorinput" id="floorinput" />
</form>
<button onclick="Calculate()">Calculate</button>

<p id="calcresult"></p>
```

In above snippet I just used packsize as a random no like 123 and your code works fine..issue is in your php part and not anywhere else..

**Also Recommended**: remove your `action=""` as it causes erratic behaviour in chrome and other browsers.. a form without action will submit to same page by default.

Comment: Brilliant thank you. Yeah I found the problem, it was with my js file link in the end.